# Check if a div has been resized in angular 4

Tags: html, angular

Is there a way to check if a div has been resized in angular 4? For example if a CSS class with different height and width for the div is attached to it.

Initially `<div class="abc"></div>`

After an event `<div class="abc xyz"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div #divRef class="abc" (event)="checkStyleClass()"></div>
```

In your component,

```
@ViewChild('devRef') element: ElementRef;

    checkStyleClass() {
                let classes = [];
                classes = this.element.nativeElement.classList;
                if (classes) {
                  classes.forEach(classVal => {
                    if (classVal === 'xyz') {
                      // div contains the xyz class after the event
                    }
                  });
                }
              }
```